# Making less print to stdout if an entire file can be displayed on one screen

Tags: less, more

When `more` is passed a file whose contents can be displayed on one screen, it just writes the file's contents to stdout without pagination. If the file cannot fit on one screen, `more` paginates it.

`less` has an option to quit if the file it is working with can be displayed on one screen (`-F`) and it has a `more`-emulation feature that behaves in a similar manner to the `-F` flag, but neither of these options seems to cause `less` to write the file's contents to stdout if the contents can fit on one screen.

How can I get `less` to write a file's contents to stdout if the file's contents can fit on one screen and paginate the file as it normally would otherwise?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use `less -FX`. From `man less`:

```
   -F or --quit-if-one-screen
          Causes less to automatically exit if the entire file can be dis-
          played on the first screen.

   -X or --no-init
          Disables sending the termcap initialization and deinitialization
          strings  to  the  terminal.   This is sometimes desirable if the
          deinitialization string does something unnecessary, like  clear-
          ing the screen.
```

Comment: Why does `-F` only work with `-X`?

Comment: @Jesse It actually works fine without `-X`, just not as you expect. Since less is a pager that acts on the alternate screen in your terminal, if you don't disable the termcap initialisation, it will both start *and* quit on the alternate screen. You'll probably see a quick flash.

Comment: So I don't see anything with `echo lol | LESS=F less` because it prints on an alternate screen and immediately switches back? Makes sense I guess (although I don't see a quick flash). Thanks.

Comment: Bah! I wonder what the hell the less developers thought when using the alternate screen if -F is present and "used". It makes no sense at all to use the alternate screen in this case.

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/107315/85237 for making `less -F` work without `-X`.