# less --quit-if-one-screen without --no-init

Tags: less

I'm on a terminal that supports the alternate screen which is used by less, vim, etc. to restore the previous display after exiting. That's a nice feature, but it really breaks the `--quit-if-one-screen` switch of `less` since in that case less switches to the alternate screen, displays its data, figures out there is only one screen, and exits, taking the contents of the alternate screen with it.

The commonly suggested workaround is using the `--no-init` switch to avoid using the alternate screen altogether. However, this is somewhat ugly because I *do* want to use it in case less actually acts as a pager. Therefore I'm looking for a solution to use the alternate screen only if less doesn't terminate automatically.

I'll mostly use this as Git's pager, so a wrapper shell script that only runs less in case there is enough output would be fine, too. At least if there's no way to do it without one.

Comment: @thieMaster in this case how do you define alternate-screen ? I try to clean some tags and I really don't get the meaning here

Comment: Related: [What is the best way to pipe the output of a command through a pager if (and only if) it is too long?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/245064)

Answer (score 27):

Since less 530 (released in December 2017), `less --quit-if-one-screen` does not switch to the alternate screen if it reads less than one screenful. So you won't have this problem if your version of less is recent enough.

In earlier versions, less has to decide whether to use the alternate screen when it starts. You can't defer that choice to when it terminates.

You could call less, let it use the alternate screen, and cat the content onto the primary screen if less terminates automatically. However I don't know of a way to detect automatic termination.

On the other hand, it isn't that difficult to call cat for short inputs and less for larger inputs, even preserving buffering so that you don't have to wait for the whole input to start seeing stuff in less (the buffer may be slightly larger — you won't see anything until you have at least one screenful of data — but not much more).

```
#!/bin/sh
n=3  # number of screen lines that should remain visible in addition to the content
lines=
newline='
'
case $LINES in
  ''|*[!0-9]*) exec less;;
esac
while [ $n -lt $LINES ] && IFS= read -r line; do
  lines="$lines$newline$line"
done
if [ $n -eq $LINES ]; then
  { printf %s "$lines"; exec cat; } | exec less
else
  printf %s "$lines"
fi
```

You might prefer to see the lines on the main screen as they come in, and switch to the alternate screen if the lines would cause scrolling.

```
#!/bin/sh
n=3  # number of screen lines that should remain visible in addition to the content
beginning=
newline='
'
# If we can't determine the terminal height, execute less directly
[ -n "$LINES" ] || LINES=$(tput lines) 2>/dev/null
case $LINES in
  ''|*[!0-9]*) exec less "$@";;
esac
# Read and display enough lines to fill most of the terminal
while [ $n -lt $LINES ] && IFS= read -r line; do
  beginning="$beginning$newline$line"
  printf '%s\n' -- "$line"
  n=$((n + 1))
done
# If the input is longer, run the pager
if [ $n -eq $LINES ]; then
  { printf %s "$beginning"; exec cat; } | exec less "$@"
fi
```

Comment: "Less has to decide whether to use the alternate screen when it starts. You can't defer that choice to when it terminates." - although it apparently doesn't do it, but couldn't it simply defer any output (such as terminal initialization commands or actual data) until it has received X lines. If stdin is exhausted while X<TERMINAL_LINES it would simply dump everything on stdout and exit, otherwise it would initialize the alternate screen and do what it's supposed to do

Comment: I ended up using a modified version of your first code example: https://gist.github.com/ThiefMaster/8331024 ($LINES was empty when called as git-pager and I think you forgot incrementing `$n`)

Comment: @ThiefMaster Thanks for the feedback. Note that you should put `#!/bin/bash` in your script since you're using bash-specific construct, as it is your script won't work on systems (such as Ubuntu) where `/bin/sh` is not bash.

Comment: I really liked this idea, and developed it a bit further (with more features): https://github.com/stefanheule/smartless

Comment: @ThiefMaster: `less` could also (but doesn't) have an optional way to quit where it prints the current contents of the screen *after* sending the un-init string.  So you could have the benefit of the alternate screen not cluttering the scrollback, but still leave the relevant part of the man-page or whatever on the terminal after exiting.

Comment: This is now out of date, less has been fixed. See eigengrau82's answer below.

Comment: Is your script of interest for those with less <530? Do I need `cat` if I have less >=530?

Comment: @Timo You don't need to do anything if you have less ≥530.

Comment: There's a strange behavior with `--quit-if-one-screen` that would be funny if it wasn't so rage-inducing. If it doesn't fit in the screen initially, `less` starts, for which it naturally uses alternate mode, and then I expand the terminal (which is a common and easy operation with a tmux pane), thus expanding the screen, making it fit in one screen, **less just up and quits** leaving me holding the bag with alternate screen having "helpfully" cleaned out even whatever portion was visible at the time. This is a rather big flaw in the design of `--quit-if-one-screen`... (tested in less 551)

Comment: It may be safe to say that this is a bug in `less`. If `less` has opened up some content for me to consume using alternate screen, under no circumstances should it then be allowed to auto-quit without being commanded to do so.

Answer (score 13):

*GNU less* v. 530 incorporates the Fedora-patch referred to by @paul-antoine-arras and will no longer output the terminal initialization sequence when `--quit-if-one-screen` is used and the input fits on one screen.

Comment: Homebrew users on Mac OS can get this behavior immediately by running `brew install less`, and making sure `$LESS` has F and omits X.

Comment: This is my favorite answer. I immediately downloaded Less 5.3.0 from GNU and compiled it myself. Great hint!

Answer (score 5):

For slow inputs, like `git log -Gregex`, do you want:

A) lines to appear on the main screen as they come in, then switch to the alternate screen once scrolling is needed (so the first `$LINES` of output will always appear in your scrollback); if so, go with the 2nd of [Gilles's answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/107355/85237).

B) lines to appear on the alternate screen, but quit the alternate screen and print the lines to the main screen if scrolling turns out to be unnecessary (so no output will appear in your scrollback if scrolling was required); if so, use the script below:

It `tee`s the input to a temporary file, then once `less` exits it `cat`s the temporary file if it contains fewer lines than the screen height:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# Needed so less doesn't prevent trap from working.
set -m
# Keeps this script alive when Ctrl+C is pressed in less,
# so we still cat and rm $TMPFILE afterwards.
trap '' EXIT

TXTFILE=$(mktemp 2>/dev/null || mktemp -t 'tmp')

tee "$TXTFILE" | LESS=-FR command less "$@"

[[ -n $LINES ]] || LINES=$(tput lines)
[[ -n $COLUMNS ]] || COLUMNS=$(tput cols)
# Wrap lines before counting, unless you pass --chop-long-lines to less
# (the perl regex strips ANSI escapes).
if (( $(perl -pe 's/\e\[?.*?[\@-~]//g' "$TXTFILE" | fold -w "$COLUMNS" | wc -l) < $LINES )); then
    cat "$TXTFILE"
fi

rm "$TXTFILE"
```

Use it with `export PAGER='/path/to/script'`. That should be enough to make `git` use it, unless you've already overridden `core.pager`.

For possible enhancements, see also my slightly more fleshed version of this script at: https://github.com/johnmellor/scripts/blob/master/bin/least

Answer (score 4):

This has long been solved in Red Hat-based distros by modifying the behavior of the -F option in `less` source code: see [this patch](http://pkgs.fedoraproject.org/cgit/rpms/less.git/tree/less-444-Foption.v2.patch) from the Fedora Project, whose first version dates back to 2008.
The idea is simply to get the height of the terminal (i.e. the maximum number of lines that can be displayed at once) and to omit the initialization and deinitialization sequences when the file fits in one screen. Thus, no need for the -X option and -F can be used consistently whatever the file length.