# pager "less": --quit-if-one-screen without --no-init

Tags: terminal, less, ncurses

I can't get `less --quit-if-one-screen` (`-F`) working without `--no-init` (`-X`).

```
less --quit-if-one-screen  /proc/uptime
```

I see no output.

This works:

```
less --quit-if-one-screen  --no-init /proc/uptime
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: For pretty much the same question, see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167735/ .

Answer (score 0):

This is bug/feature request number 303: http://www.greenwoodsoftware.com/less/bugs.html

> When -F is used, don't output terminal initialization and exit
>   sequences when only one screen is displayed.

Sorry, this is just an explanation, not a solution. I guess the maintainer would accept a patch which solves this.