# How to write less buffer to stdout in interactive mode

Tags: pipe, stdout, less

My scenario is the following:
When I ask the *psql* program for *\help*, it pipes its output to *less*. Sometimes, I would like to keep the help contents while writing my next query. I imagine this could happen if I could tell *less* to write to stdout, like *more* would do, **while in interactive mode**.

Restrictions:

I will decide whether or not this should happen AFTER I have seen the
contents of \help. So, customizing the pager used by psql is (I
think) not an option. This means that my question is not a duplicate
of:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14474138/customize-pager-in-psql

or:

[Making less print to stdout if an entire file can be displayed on one screen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75866/making-less-print-to-stdout-if-an-entire-file-can-be-displayed-on-one-screen)

What I am currently using:

```
\setenv PAGER more OR \setenv PAGER 'less -X'
\help alter user
q (to exit less or more)
-- Now I can write my query while looking at the alter user syntax above
```

What is lacking in this approach is that I would like to choose whether I want the -X option or not AFTER I have looked at the contents. I can imagine that less can achieve that by writing to both the main and the alternate buffer.

Comment: The [manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/less) indicates that the you can just type in '-X' during interactive mode. Can you try this and see if it works?

Comment: Check the `|` command in the `less(1)` manpage. For instance, if you type `|<Enter>cat<Enter>`, you will have the current content left on the screen after you exit or suspend `less`. Check `lesskey(1)` if you want to do that with a single key.

Comment: Thanks, @UncleBilly , your comment provides the best solution, because it works without even modifying any settings. If you write it as an answer, I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: Hi, @Haxiel, when I type -X I get: "Cannot change the -X (--no-init) option  (press RETURN)" This happens both inside psql and regular bash

Answer (score 2):

You could provide your own pager script that saves the output as well as giving it to `less`. Then on exit from `less` it can choose to show the output again without `less`, or just exit. For example, assuming the output help is in a pipe and `less` is not called with arguments:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
if tee /tmp/save | less -K
then    cat /tmp/save
fi
```

The `-K` makes `less` quit on <kbd>control-c</kbd> and this changes the return code from `less` to 2 instead of 0. So if you quit `less` normally the `cat` will repeat the input, but if you interrupt it, you will get no extra output.